# Angled vs. curved routing in PCB design specifically for SPI communication

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, routing

In PCB design, it's common to observe angled routings, yet curved routings are believed to offer better performance. Would using exclusively curved routings pose any issues in the PCB layout? Can someone clarify the differences in performance and potential considerations between angled and curved routing approaches?

[image: Curve routing For SPI]

[image: Angled Routing]

Comment: It's really just preference. As long as the transmission doesn't reflect, you can use any shape you want. Think about it like a ball being dropped down a hole in the ground. As long as the ball doesn't bounce back up, it will continue going downwards.

Comment: Unless you are close to, or above 2GHz then it *matters not*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely nothing!  It looks cool, that's all.

Maybe could be used to optimize routing density the tiniest bit, as the arcs can be stacked concentrically, whereas octagonal routes must stick out in the corners (and if snapped to grid, the diagonals will necessarily be spaced wider than the orthogonals, as a sqrt(2) slope can never be grid-aligned).  Pretty rare use-case, I'd say, but it's an option.

Compare wavelength or edge rate (at the speed of light in the medium, i.e. including velocity factor in microstrip/stripline) to the radius of curvature; when wavelength is comparable or shorter, it can be perceptible in terms of a bump in impedance at that point along the transmission line, or with the trace as an antenna.  We would therefore prefer larger radii -- gentler curves, smoother transitions -- for the highest frequencies, when the most stable impedance is demanded.  That is, test equipment, precision RF/analog, may demand such geometry.

For no radius (sharp ortho/octo corners), compare to the trace width -- which is to say, it really only matters for frequencies so high, the transmission line itself is near cutoff (trace width ~ λ/4).  These are high frequencies indeed, and the use of a PCB at all, becomes questionable: preferred methods may include (conventional air-filled metal) waveguides, dielectric waveguides or fiber optics, or even free-space optics.

It's unlikely that digital signals would even notice; the most likely interaction is the shift in impedance narrowing the eye, or increasing jitter (frequency-dependent amplitude effects, inter-symbol interference), which will be relevant for the most precise and demanding applications (~fs precise timing reference?).  (Standards such as PCIe, HDMI, etc. are designed with quite crude interfaces in mind -- FR-4 PCBs, cheap connectors, consumer cables, etc.  All the hard work is done by the interface chips, so that the supporting media can be as cheap as possible.)

The effect of curvature, is simply to stretch out (in time) and flatten out (in impedance), that bump in the characteristic impedance Zo of the trace.  The width of the arc may also change depending on its curvature, to better maintain Zo.

You do see, from time to time, references where orthogonal routing has been done, with the corner clipped, chamfered -- there exists a calculation for this chamfer, to minimize Zo error along the trace.  This could be seen as the limiting case of an arc segment of different trace width, as the chamfer effectively looks like a necked-down arc.

Again, even this is a small effect; in this case, the change in Zo might be modest (say, ±10%? I forget what the actual numbers are), and only in the vicinity of the corner, i.e. the trace length of differing Zo is very short.  At lower frequencies, it looks like a lumped equivalent, a small L or C on the line.

See: https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/mitered-bends for better detail.

Regarding corners as antennas, really it matters more in terms of the change in boundary conditions: straight microstrip lines *are already antennas*, and we're not concerned about that *per se*, but the change in amount, particularly if it's ever higher.  In other words, are there frequencies, signal levels, and emissions thresholds, such that the corner-turn can look like a sort-of-flattened 1/4-wave whip, or patch, or dipole or loop, type antenna?  Again, these will only be pronounced effects at the highest frequencies, near cutoff, and can be safely ignored at low frequencies.

(A far stronger concern for emission, is whether the overall trace is sinuous, for example a trace that wiggles around will have a phase shift between segments which can therefore have all segments act in phase at some unlucky frequency, making a sort of phased-array multi-patch antenna; but for this purpose, the cornering of the trace is irrelevant, it's the topology that matters.)